# Is there a way to run a c# program from jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a program I wrote that gets two parameters and set some files to be upload, and I want to know if I can run it from Jmeter before performing the HTTP upload requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)  to invoke the `.exe` file of your C# program.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any program using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language. If you don't want this execution to appear in the .jtl results file you can use i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) instead.

The relevant code will be as simple as:

```
 "your_command".execute()
```

If you need the command output, you can amend it as:

```
"your_command".execute().text
```

The approach works on any operating system. See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn what else could be done with Groovy.